# Last folder structure before the re-imaged drive

Tags: backup, verification

Owning a Vaio computer with a factory image available in the drive. Lately I have backed up everything and using the Assist button, I have reversed the computer to factory state by simply using the factory recovery option which reflashes the image on the drive.  I have made my backup before doing this.

Now I want to check if all my files are well copied back or not?

Is there a way to display the latest folder and file structure of the hard drive before this reflash action?

Comment: It's possible, yes, but it's difficult and probably not worth the effort. You're looking for information on Data Recovery. If you're just looking to duplicate the pre-image folder structure, you should have recorded that folder structure prior to reimaging.

Comment: It depends on what software you used to back up, but most back-up packages offer a the ability to browse a back-up and recover selected files and folders. If you can browse your back-up, then its integrity is probably OK. It won't do any harm to perform a disk check on wherever you are holding the back-up. Whether you backed up all the files you needed is another matter.